# How to connect a text box to another worksheet by using userform (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Actually i use this code to connect a text box to another worksheet.However, nothing changed
SO here we have *LastRow* which is i made it in order to count the last written row to make the info sequentially arranged
and *Datafrm* my userform`s name

````
Private Sub butAdd_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet("DataBase").Range("A:A"))

Sheets("DataBase").Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = LastRow
Sheets("DataBase").Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = Datafrm.txtName.Value

End Sub```
````

Comment: This code actually must throw an error because of `Sheet("DataBase").Range("A:A")` it has to be `Sheets` not `Sheet`.

Comment: thanks man , but it did not work

Comment: Well, can you give us more infomation? Do you get any errors? Did you go through your code step by step using F8 and check the variable values? What is the value of `LastRow`? What is the value of `Datafrm.txtName.Value`? Debug your code and check it ([Debugging VBA Code](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code)).

Comment: ok man i edited my post

Comment: *Where* does nothing change? Your code currently writes the LastRow variable to column A and a textbox value from datafrm to Column B. The syntax is OK (though you should qualify your workbook if you want to use more than 1 in your routine) so are both those values writing to your Database sheet Ok?

Comment: Well but you didn't tell the values of the variables. Nor did you tell what you found out by going through your code step by step using F8. So the most likely issue in your code is that `LastRow` is not the row you expect it to be therefore I asked you to check its value.